# Having issues with code output with my program. Updated with new bushel basket class

Tags: java, output

(NOW WITH UPDATED CODE)Having serious issues trying to get the right output from my program.  I need to have a specific output from this program and it is expect to be this output:

```
Rick...
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 33 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 29 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.
Newt...
This bushel basket has 100 apples in it.
false
false
100
25
Michele...
true
false
false
false
false
true
Herman...
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.
Jon...
This bushel basket has 125 apples in it.
Ron...
This bushel basket has 20 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 125 apples in it.
Gary...
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.
```

HOWEVER I received the output:

```
Rick...
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 33 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 29 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.
Newt...
This bushel basket has 100 apples in it.
false
false
100(THIS IS WHERE THE BAD OUTPUT STARTS)
true
Michele...
true
false
false
false
false
true
Herman...
This bushel basket has -5 apples in it.
Jon...
This bushel basket has 300 apples in it.
Ron...
This bushel basket has 20 apples in it.
This bushel basket has -30 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 960 apples in it.
Gary...
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.
```

here is the code

```
    public class AppleOrchard
    {
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Rick...");
            BushelBasket rick = new BushelBasket(0);
            rick.print();
            rick.pick(11);
            rick.pick(22);
            rick.print();
            rick.eat(4);
            rick.print();
            rick.spill();
            rick.print();

            System.out.println("Newt...");
            BushelBasket newt = new BushelBasket(100);
            newt.print();

            System.out.println( newt.isEmpty() );
            System.out.println( newt.isFull() );
            System.out.println( newt.getApples() );
            System.out.println( newt.roomLeftInBasket() );

            System.out.println("Michele...");
            BushelBasket michele = new BushelBasket(0);
            System.out.println( michele.isEmpty() );
            System.out.println( michele.isFull() );
            michele.pick(25);
            System.out.println( michele.isEmpty() );
            System.out.println( michele.isFull() );
            michele.pick(100);
            System.out.println( michele.isEmpty() );
            System.out.println( michele.isFull() );

            System.out.println("Herman...");
            BushelBasket herman = new BushelBasket(-5); // should default to 0
            herman.print();

            System.out.println("Jon...");
            BushelBasket jon = new BushelBasket(300); // should default to 125
            jon.print();

            System.out.println("Ron...");
            BushelBasket ron = new BushelBasket(20); // starts with 20
            ron.print();
            ron.eat(50); // can only eat down to zero apples
            ron.print(); // should see zero apples
            ron.eat(10); // back to 10
            ron.pick(1000); // basket can only hold 125 apples
            ron.print(); // should print 125

            System.out.println("Gary...");
            BushelBasket gary = new BushelBasket(0); // should default to 0
            gary.print();
        }
    }



    class BushelBasket
{
        int apples;

        BushelBasket(int apples) 
        {
    if (apples > 0 && apples < 125)
      this.apples = apples;
        }

        public void spill()
        {
            apples = 0;
        }

        public void pick(int x)
        {
            if (!isFull())
                apples = apples + x;
        }

        public void eat(int x)
        {
            if (!isEmpty())
                apples = apples - x;
        }

        public int getApples()
        {
            return apples;  
        }

        public void print()
        {
            int x = getApples();
            System.out.println("This bushel basket has " + x + " apples in it.");
        }

        public boolean isEmpty()
        {
            int emtpy = 0;

            if (apples <= emtpy)
            {   
                return true;
            }

            else 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean isFull()
        {
            int full = 125;

            if (apples >= full)
            {   
                return true;
            }

            else 
            {
                return false;
            }

        }



        public boolean roomLeftInBasket()
        {
            int full = 125;

            if (apples < full)
            {   
                return true;
            }

            else 
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Bhavik Shah I didn't realize that didn't post properly!

Answer (score 0):

*Newt*

your code has

```
System.out.println( newt.getApples() );                      // integer
System.out.println( newt.roomLeftInBasket() );               // boolean
```

this won't return `100 25` as you expect, it will return `100 true`

It looks like you need to change your `roomLeftInBasket()` method to return the amount left in the basket, or change the code so that it looks something like:

```
if (newt.roomLeftInBasket())
{
  System.out.println( newt.fullBasket() - newt.getApples());
}
```

but you'll have to create the `fullBasket()` method

*Herman*

In the constructor for Herman, you give his basket -5 apples.  If you cannot have a negative basket, you will have to change the constructor to check for this.

*Jon*

Same as for Herman, but you need to check if the value of the created basket is greater than  a full basket and change it accordingly.

*Ron*

For Ron, you need to check whether the value given to eat() is greater than the value in the basket and deal with the situation where Ron tries to eat more apples than he has in the basket.

Comment: @BhavikShah You declare it as so: `public boolean roomLeftInBasket() {`

Comment: Tried this and doesn't work.  Get errors while attempting to compile. Create public boolean roomLeftInbasket() but didnt help

Comment: you already have `public boolean roomLeftInbasket()`. You need `public int fullBasket();`

Comment: I'm sorry it's really late and I dont know what else I need to do to fix my program.  The public intfullbasket() is supposed to contain what exactly?

Comment: The number of apples in a full basket.  It probably makes more sense to change `public boolean roomLeftInbasket()` to return an int instead of a boolean.  Either way, you need to get a number (instead of true/false).

Comment: I just keep getting error messages when I try to make the public int fullBasket as well as trying to change the boolean to return a int.  I'm calling a quits and just taking an E for this assignment, I'm exhausted and don't understand this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: nahh, don't quit.  change roomLeftInBasket to this:

    public int roomLeftInBasket()
    {
        int full = 125;
        if (apples >= full)
        {
           return 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            return  full - apples;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

change the constructor

```
BushelBasket(int apples) 
{
   if (apples < 0 )
      this.apples = 0;
   else if(apples >125)
      this.apples = 125;
   else
      this.apples=apples;
}
```